# Instructing Pip to Use Python 3

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I'm using Ubuntu, how do I instruct `pip` to use the `Python3` installation and not `Python2.6`? 2.6 is the default installation on Ubuntu. I can't upgrade that as it will break Ubuntu.

Comment: Is there a `pip3` command installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any single `pip` installation is (roughly) specific to one Python installation. You can, however, have multiple parallel `pip` installations. Your package manager probably has a package called `pip-3.3` or similar. If not, you can manually install it (run the `get-pip.py` script using Python 3.3), though you'll have to be careful that it ends up in the right place in `PATH`. You can also use a `virtualenv`.

Answer (score 0):

Install pip by downloading the source and doing:

```
python3 setup.py install
```

Then, you should have a `pip3` or a `pip-3.3` command that you can use, to instruct pip to install whatever package using python3

Conversely, if you want to migrate to python3 entirely, do `which python` and follow the symlinks to `/usr/local/bin` (I think). There, you should be able to `sudo ln -s` to change what `python` points to

Comment: The last option is a bad idea if the system uses Python 2.6 by default - lots of scripts, including important system tools, will rely on `python` being 2.6 rather than 3.

Comment: @delnan: good point. I assumed a fairly contemporary ubuntu install, which I shouldn't have

Comment: Did I miss 13.10 switching to 3.x by default, or does "fairly contemporary" mean "not yet released"? ;-)

Comment: @delnan: I meant that I haven't seen a dependency on 2.6 for a while, and switching hasn't made much of a difference on my machines (that I've seen so far)

Comment: Well, a few tools on my 13.04 machine throw a tarantrum when I run them in a 3.3 virtualenv, so I deduce it's not universally fixed (yet). Note that Python code written for 2.7 is (almost) as likely to be Python 3 incompatible. *Something* delayed Ubuntu making Python 3 the default (plans for that switch date back at least a year or two).

Comment: @delnan: in that case, I'm entirely wrong. Thank you for pointing this out #til

Comment: Even when it is the default for system tools, I don't think Ubuntu has any plans to follow Arch's bad example and call the binary `python` instead of `python3`